# Can you stop jquery cycle from overwriting inline absolute position?

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

Cycle overwrites the position for the images in the div with top:0 left:0 is there a way to stop that so I can use inline positioning?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the images?

Comment: The images are absolute positioned inside the divisions already with inline css inside another program, and cycle overwrites them with 0,0. If I can turn that off I can make it become a neat addition to the wysiwyg for the users to use inside that program.

Answer (score 1):

No.. You can cycle some divs and inside those divs you can use whatever inline styles you need on the images.  Jquery Cycle uses its own positioning of the cycled elements to make the slideshow.  Here is an example:

```
<div id="slideshow">
  <div><img src="pic.png" style="margin-left:10px" /></div>
  <div><img src="pic2.png" style="margin-left:10px" /></div>
  <div><img src="pic3.png" style="margin-left:10px" /></div>
  <div><img src="pic4.png" style="margin-left:10px" /></div>
  <div><img src="pic5.png" style="margin-left:10px" /></div>
</div>

$('#slideshow').cycle();
```

Comment: Yeah the images already have the position, I thought maybe .removeAttr or something along that line but it's probably get too heavy. - thanks much

Answer (score 0):

You can write some custom css rules for each inline style, and append `!important` to each value, which will override the inline rules.